# How to Create Custom PopUpView in ios8 & ios7?

Tags: iphone, swift, uiview, popup, uipopovercontroller

I try to create subview inside a view but  view is get full screen present view

[image: i Want to create this type of view in subview. i want to customised this Subview as PopUp vIew.as my below Screen shot show.]

so Can any one guide me through that Whether its possible to Customised Subview As PopupView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by `AlertViewController`.

Here is my Forgot Password method, you can get help from that.

```
@IBAction func forgotpwd(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Forgot Password", message: "Enter Your Email.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter your Email"
        textField.keyboardType = .EmailAddress
    }

    var yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        //Do you Success button Stuff here
    }

    var noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        //Do you No button Stuff here, like dismissAlertView
    }
    alertController.addAction(yesAction)
    alertController.addAction(noAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
    }

}
```

May It help you,

HTH, Enjoy Coding!!